# Assigning shapes to variables in a correlation circle plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, pch

I would like to know if it is possible to set different shapes to the column names in the plot instead of the labels. I have shown a reproducible example to obtain the plot.

```
#dataset
mtcars

#split the data into different blocks
a<-mtcars[,1:3]
b<-mtcars[,4:6]
c<-mtcars[,7:9]
d<-mtcars[,10:11]

### create a list of dataframes
A<-list(blockA=a, blockB=b,blockC=c,blockD=d)

### design matrix
C <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0,  
              0, 0, 0, 0, 
              0, 0, 0, 0, 
              1, 1, 1, 1), 4, 4)
tau = c(1, 1, 1, 1)
library(mixOmics)

##### computing the sGCCA
wrap.result.sgcca = wrapper.sgcca(data = A, design = C, penalty = rep(1, length(A)),
  ncomp = c(2, 2, 2,2), scheme = "centroid", verbose = FALSE)

##### visualization
col <- rep(c("blue", "red", "darkgreen", "darkviolet"))

plotVar(wrap.result.sgcca, col=col, comp = c(1,2), 
  block = c(1,2,3,4), ncomp.select = c(1,2), labels = TRUE)
```

[image: Correlation circle plot]

In this plot, I have managed to color the blocks in unique colors. I would also like to represent the columns using shapes. For instance, when we consider the different column names of the dataset mtcars

```
colnames(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

According to the blocks I have split a(columns1:3), b(columns(4:6), c(columns 7:9), d(columns 10:11), I would like columns 1, 4, 7,10 to have same shapes (say circle), columns 2,5,8,11 (say square), columns 3,6,9 (say star). I tried setting the pch values but failed to produce the shapes according to column names in this plot. Could someone help me out here? Thanks